# Unable to extract field from XML element with some attribute JAVA

Tags: java, xml, java-8, jaxb

I have below code and XML file:

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        File file = new File("etc/test.xml");    
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);    

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Config obj = (Config) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(obj.getPbxprofileTable());
    }

}
```

**Config:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="config")
public class Config {

    private List<PBXProfileTable> pbxprofileTable;

    public Config() {}

    public Config(List<PBXProfileTable> pbxprofileTable) {
        super();
        this.pbxprofileTable = pbxprofileTable;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="PbxProfileTable")
    public List<PBXProfileTable> getPbxprofileTable() {
        return pbxprofileTable;
    }

    public void setPbxprofileTable(List<PBXProfileTable> pbxprofileTable) {
        this.pbxprofileTable = pbxprofileTable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Config [pbxprofileTable=" + pbxprofileTable + "]";
    }

}
```

**PBXProfileTable:**

```
public class PBXProfileTable {

private int id;

    public PBXProfileTable() {}

    public PBXProfileTable(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PBXProfileTable [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<config>
<PbxProfileTable  xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig">
    <ID>501</ID>
    <NAME>ENELITALIASRL011</NAME>
    <Record>
      <PBX_RECORD_ID>2</PBX_RECORD_ID>
      <PBX_NAME>ENELITALIASRL011</PBX_NAME>
      <STATE>Enable</STATE>
      <PBX_PRID>ENELITALIASRL011@wind.it</PBX_PRID>
      <AUTH_SCHEME>No Authentication</AUTH_SCHEME>
      <AUTH_DATA/>
      <PBX_PUID_USER>WER011</PBX_PUID_USER>
      <PBX_PUID_HOST>wind.it</PBX_PUID_HOST>
      <REGISTRAR_NAME/>
      <PBX_CONTACT_USER>WER011</PBX_CONTACT_USER>
    </Record>
  </PbxProfileTable>
  <PbxProfileTable  xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig">
    <ID>502</ID>
    <NAME>ENELITALIASRL011</NAME>
    <Record>
      <PBX_RECORD_ID>2</PBX_RECORD_ID>
      <PBX_NAME>ENELITALIASRL011</PBX_NAME>
      <STATE>Enable</STATE>
      <PBX_PRID>ENELITALIASRL011@wind.it</PBX_PRID>
      <AUTH_SCHEME>No Authentication</AUTH_SCHEME>
      <AUTH_DATA/>
      <PBX_PUID_USER>WER011</PBX_PUID_USER>
      <PBX_PUID_HOST>wind.it</PBX_PUID_HOST>
      <REGISTRAR_NAME/>
      <PBX_CONTACT_USER>WER011</PBX_CONTACT_USER>
    </Record>
  </PbxProfileTable>
 </config>
```

I want to extract `ID` from `PbxProfileTable` tag i.e. `501` and `502` from XML file as shown below:

**Output:** `[PBXProfileTable [id=501], PBXProfileTable [id=502]]`

This code works fine only if I remove `xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig"` from each `PbxProfileTable` tag i.e. `<PbxProfileTable  xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig">` in XML file. However If I run with `<PbxProfileTable  xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig">` I get `null` as an output. Can anyone help how to get above output with `<PbxProfileTable  xmlns="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig">` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PBXProfileTable ID field is also in namespace "http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig" since it is contained in PBXProfileTable.  Updating the ID field as below should worked for me.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PBXProfileTable {

    @XmlElement(name="ID" , namespace = "http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig")
    private int id;

    public PBXProfileTable() {}

    public PBXProfileTable(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PBXProfileTable [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me!! Can you please explain `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Answer (score 1):

if you use xml namespaces, you need to add them to your jaxb classes

So in your `Config` class:

```
@XmlElement(name="PbxProfileTable", namespace="http://example.com/yang/isbc-sig")
public List<PBXProfileTable> getPbxprofileTable() {
    return pbxprofileTable;
}
```

Comment: Now I am not getting `null` as result but I am getting `[PBXProfileTable [id=0], PBXProfileTable [id=0]]`. Why ID is 0?? It should be `501` and `502`.

Comment: Any help please?? I am unable to figer out issue??